# Spring Security Custom Login bad credentials with the right password

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to Spring security and I'm trying to create a custom login page. My problem is the authentication always failed and I always received the Bad Credentials message eventhough the password was correct, note that I have used BCRyptPasswordEncoder when I am saving the new registered account. Without the custom login and using the default formlogin it works fine

This is my WebSecurityConfig

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
    return new CustomApplicantDetailsService();
}

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

    return authProvider;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { //login logout
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**")
            .authenticated()
            .anyRequest()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/loginProcess")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/account")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                //.successForwardUrl("/account")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .permitAll();

}}
```

This is my TemplateController to hanlde the url request. Note that I have tried the GetMapping first with the same line of code as loginProcess and without loginprocessingURL in configure but I received the error method get not supported altho most tutorials works somehow.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TemplateController {

@GetMapping("login")
public String login(){
    return "loginStudent"; // logicalname
}

@PostMapping("loginProcess")
public String loginProcess(){

Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if(authentication == null ||authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken){
        return "loginStudent"; // logicalname
    }
    return "redirect:/account.html"; // redirect to account homepage
}
```

And here is the form from the "loginStudent.html"

```
     <form th:action="@{/loginProcess}" th:method="post" >

                <div th:if="${param.error}">
                    <p class="text-danger">.    [[${session.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}]]</p>
                </div>

                <div th:if="${param.logout}">
                    <p class="text-warning">You have been logged out.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">E-Mail Adresse:</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" id="email" name="username " autofocus="autofocus">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Passwort:</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Passwort" id="password" name="password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"> Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: Your `name` should be `email` not `username`.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you so much Mr.Deinum, this solved my problem. I thought the problem was much bigger. I have seen your answers on this topic and I am very thankful

Comment: @M.Deinum great catch!